# GDI Modify Font in MFC

Tags: c++, fonts, mfc, gdi

I have a MFC application that uses GDI for drawing.

When I want to draw out some text I make a new font and call TextOut method on the device context:

```
CFont font;
font.CreateFontW(20,0,-100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,CString("Arial"));
CFont *oldfont = ctx->SelectObject(&font);

ctx->TextOutW(50, 50, CString("123"));
```

And that works great. Now I want to change the font a little bit (adjust the escapement). Can I do that with existing `font`, or do I have to make a new CFont?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to create a new `CFont` as there are no members for modifying it after it has been created and I'm not aware of any Win32 functions that can do that on the contained `HFONT` handle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new font.